# python unexpected AttributeError

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python, and as a exercise I wrote a simple reverse function.

the code:

```
def m_reverse(x):
     if len(x) == 1:
             return x
     return m_reverse(x[:-1]).insert(0,x[-1])
```

when I try it I get the following:

```
>>> m_reverse([1,2,3,4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in m_reverse
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in m_reverse
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

what's my mistake? Any critical data I'm lacking?

Comment: As a side note: Because `[x][:-1]` is legal (and returns an empty list), you could use an empty list as your base case instead of `len(x) == 1`. That would make your code a little simpler, and also make it work on empty lists instead of raising an exception. See [here](http://pastebin.com/RFED74p0) for an example (with mgilson's fix included).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with python builtin functions, if the function mutates the argument in place, by convention it returns `None`.  So, since `.insert` mutates the list, it returns `None`.

Your idea is good, and I think the logic makes sense -- From an implementation standpoint, rather than using `insert`, you could use list concatenation:

```
def m_reverse(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
       return lst
    else:
       return [lst[-1]] + m_reverse(lst[:-1])
       # return lst[-1:] + m_reverse(lst[:-1]) would also work.
```

Comment: any non-destruct functions that will do the same? something like lisps cons?

Comment: @elyashiv -- a developer can do whatever they want.  I'm just saying what is *conventional*.  There are a few notable exceptions.  `list.pop` and `dict.pop` are two such exceptions.

Comment: @mgilson: The convention is that mutating methods don't return `self`, not that they don't return anything. Since `pop` has something useful to return (the popped value), it returns that. Since `insert` has nothing useful to return, it returns `None`.

Comment: @elyashiv: The reason Python doesn't come with functions like `cons` is that it would be misleading. A Python list is a variable length array, not a single-linked list. So, algorithms that repeatedly concatenate new items onto the front, which are the fastest way to do things in Lisp, are the _slowest_ way to do things in Python.

Comment: @elyashiv: So, you could write `def cons(x, ys): return [x] + ys`, but you probably shouldn't; better to rewrite your code to work from the other end, like [this](http://pastebin.com/gjA2z6we). (Of course it's usually even _better_ to write Pythonic code instead of Lisp-style code in the first place.)

Comment: @abarnert -- I think that I remember reading somewhere (though I can't remember where now) that methods should return `None` if they mutate the object unless it leads to a significant "inconvenience".  In this case, `list.pop` fits the bill because there is no other way to get at the value `pop`ped out.  But, ultimately, that's pretty much just saying what you already said in a different way.  since `.pop` has a meaningful value to return and since getting at that value would be inconvenient otherwise, `.pop` returns something even though it mutates `self`.

Comment: @abarnert what's the Pythonic way to do this? (aside of calling build in functions)

Comment: @elyashiv -- For this example?  use the builtin (`reversed`).  Otherwise, the next best bet is to eliminate the recursion...

Comment: @elyashiv: Aside from calling built-in functions, slicing with `[::-1]`. But that's probably cheating. One option is to do this iteratively, using an explicit stack instead of the implicit recursion stack, and using a data structure that _is_ good at left-insertion (like a `collections.deque`), like [this](http://pastebin.com/AQkcsaKB). Another is to copy the list, then mutate the copy in-place, like [this](http://pastebin.com/t7EGq49T). Or you could use a recursive or iterative _generator_ that yields the values one by one instead of building up a list of them.

Comment: @mgilson: Nick Coghlan explained somewhere that "mutating methods should return `None`" isn't really accurate, except as a shortcut for "mutating methods should return something other than `self`, which means `None` if there is nothing else they need to return, as is usually the case". Guido has agreed with that sentiment multiple times, and each time soon gone back to using the imprecise shortcut anyway. It's certainly a much easier rule to state, and to remember, and it's not _that_ hard to figure out why `pop` violates the rule…